# Java - Word palindrome for LONG strings

Tags: java, palindrome

So, I'm doing this challenge called [valid palindrome](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/) and I'm stuck.

My code works for small/medium strings but when it runs I get a `Time Limit Exceeded` message which means there has to be a better way to optimize my code.

I was looking at using the `charAt()` and do something like ... since it's a palindrome... split it half and do a quick check of opposing characters in a for loop but I'm stuck here.

```
/**
 *  Palindrome Word Checker
 *  Tests to see if an input phrase is a
 *  palindrome (read the same if read backward and forwards)
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordPalindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Palindrome Word Checker\nEnter a phrase, please:");

        String theWord = "";

        while (true) {
            theWord = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(theWord + ": " + wordPalindrome(theWord));
        }
    }
    public static boolean wordPalindrome(String word) {

        // SECONDLY, we check to see how we much of the word
        // is left until verification. We check first to prevent
        //  array (out of bounds) exception errors.


        if (word.length() == 0 || word.length() == 1) return true;

        // FIRST we take the last letter and compare it to the first letter
        // if it matches, then we move onward and return to the function
        // with a new word. By substring(), we take off the first/last letters
        // and we keep repeating this process until the length is
        // at 0 or 1 for odd/even lengthed words to verify its status
        if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == word.charAt(0))
            return wordPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));

        // if we fail to make an ID, then it's obviously
        // not a palindrome and we return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is what "string" they use to crash my program: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ScXUxsmv). How do I withstand a string that long? I can't obviously use String since it's so long... too much info.

Comment: have you considered using [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29)?

Comment: LOL! why are you testing such a big string. Anyway this code is absolutely not appropriate, you are using recursion for that, which is costly. Use loops instead.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes but StringBuilder still says my string is too long.

Comment: @afzalex I am using a big string because my assisgment said too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way than recursion would be an iterative process. You can use `charAt` and a loop that processes half the string and the other half at the same time. I won't code it up, but I'll ive pseudocode that you could try to use. I recommend coding it up in Java as a challenge to yourself:

1. Determine length of the string
2. Initialize counter (i) to 0.
3. While i is less than length minus i, repeat the following:

   1. If the i'th character is not equal to (length-i)th character, return false immediately.
4. Once loop ends, return true (since no failures were found).

Comment: Thanks you, this is what I wanted. A guiding. I'll post back my results.

Comment: I did it! Thank you for not giving me the answer. I mean, I ALREADY had most of the pseudo-code in my hand but you gave me the ah-ha moment. I learned a lot from this. http://pastebin.com/QADmYmEP

Comment: @DanF Have you tested with input data?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should follow hexafraction's advice and try to code it yourself. If you are interested in coding challenges like the one you are struggling with right now you can also visit:

- [topcoder](http://topcoder.com)
- [SPOJ](http://spoj.com)
- [codechef](http://codechef.com)
- [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com)

And just in case solution that should pass palindrome task:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").toLowerCase();
    int b = 0;
    int e = s.length()-1;

    while(b < e) {
        if(s.charAt(b++) != s.charAt(e--))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `StringBuilder` as well:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(word);
return sb.equals(sb.reverse());
```

Quick and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion for this.

Just replace folowing

```
if (word.charAt(word.length() - 1) == word.charAt(0))
    return wordPalindrome(word.substring(1, word.length() - 1));
```

with this

```
int length = word.length();
for(int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
    if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(length - i - 1)){
        return false; // not palindrome
    }
}
return true; // palindrome
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `word.charAt(length - i - 1)`? This task is a bit more complex because it requires to match sentence `"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"` as a palindrome as well.

Comment: @MaciejDonajski Thanks, editted. How "A man, aplan, a canal: Panama" could be palindrome?

Comment: @afzalex By removing the non-letter symbols and ignoring the case, you'd get "amanaplanacanalpanama" which is a palindrome.

Comment: @TNT But the user's program is also not doing this. I just have written equivalent code with a little optimization

Answer (score 0):

Use the **java.io** package.
Then you could use the following line of code:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(theWord).reverse();  
if (theWord.equals(str)) {  
System.out.println("Palindrome");  
}  
else {  
System.out.println("Not Palindrome");  
}
```